# Cannot use setCurrentTime() in Chrome with mediaelement.js

Tags: mediaelement.js, mediaelement

It seems that the following code works in Firefox but not in Chrome, with a variety of file formats such as .ogg and .mp3.  In other words, I am unable to get the audio to change to the desired time before, during or after it is done playing in Chrome.

```
mediaPlayer.setCurrentTime(seekSeconds)
```

The load process before playing is very simple:

```
$('#mediaPlayer').attr('src', mediaUrl);
mediaPlayer = new MediaElement('mediaPlayer', {
  media.play();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

MEJS can't set the time until the media is loaded. Use the "loadeddata" event.

```
$('#video').bind('loadeddata', function(e) {
 if (player.readyState) player.setCurrentTime(duration);
});
```

or this: [How to add events to flash fallback for medialemetn and what evets are available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930990/how-to-add-events-to-flash-fallback-for-medialemetn-and-what-evets-are-available)